# Using call on a union of multiple function types differing by return type

Tags: typescript, types

My function has a callback typed as a union of multiple function types, each having the same set of formal arguments, but different return types. This code:

```
type FA = () => string;
type FB = () => number;

function f( callback: FA | FB ) {
    callback.call( {} );
}
```

... produces TS2684 error:

```
(TS) The 'this' context of type 'FA | FB' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type '(this: {}) => string'.
    Type 'FB' is not assignable to type '(this: {}) => string'.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

However, this:

```
type FixCallbackUnion<T extends ( this: ThisParameterType<T>, ...a: any ) => any> =
    ( this: ThisParameterType<T>, ...a: Parameters<T> ) => ReturnType<T>;

type FA = () => string;
type FB = () => number;

function f( callback: FA | FB ) {
    ( <FixCallbackUnion<typeof callback>>callback ).call( {} );
}
```

... compiles normally while seemingly keeping all the involved types exactly the same.

How can I fix the first example to make it work, or do I have to use a workaround from the second one?

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33815 .  Right now the fact that this doesn't work for unions of functions looks like a missing feature.  You'll have to use some sort of workaround; my suggestion would be to just widen `(()=>A)|(()=>B)` to `()=>(A|B)` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0y3rW).  Does that address your question fully or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz: it does, thank you. That's exactly the issue I ran into. I think I'll stick with my type casting workaround though, so as not to emit any extra code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jcalz points in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72079782/using-call-on-a-union-of-multiple-function-types-differing-by-return-type/72079935#comment127359361_72079782), this is a shortcoming of TypeScript as of version 4.6.2 ([#33815](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33815)).

The workaround is to use `call` on a value that's no longer a union of function types, by either specifying the type explicitly on your own or using the type system to compute the required type for you (see the question for an example on how to do that).

What seems to be an actual fix (so far) is to use interface merging and add another signature for `call`:

```
interface CallableFunction extends Function {
    call<T extends ( ...args: any[] ) => any>(
        this: T,
        thisArg: ThisParameterType<T>,
        ...a: Parameters<T>
    ): ReturnType<T>;
}
```

With it, the first example from the question works as is.

Comment: Hmm, well I was going to write up an answer myself but I guess this also suffices.

Answer (score 0):

..should look something like this:
Sorry.. I tested this in a class, to make this example work I had to call the functions directly. Anyway.. using .call(this?) may make sense in your code anyway.
To get two different types as return value (I guess thats the question about) you have to specify them AND of course return the return-value of the inner function as well.

Let me know if I missed something.

```
type FA = () => string;
type FB = () => number;

function f( callback: FA | FB ): string | number {
    return callback();
}

let A: FA = function() { return "string"; }; 
let x = f(A);
console.log(x);

let B: FB = function() { return 3; };
let y = f(B);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: This code generates a compiler error for me, see [here](https://tsplay.dev/wEv3bN).  Even if this does work, you might want to explain what's going on with words and why it addresses the question as asked.

Comment: `TS2555 (TS) Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0.` on `call()`. Also, actually handling returned values is irrelevant for this minimal example.

Comment: @jcalz: edited my example-- hope that helps

Comment: @Wolfgang: as the question says, this is about using `.call` on the function, not simply calling it.

Comment: @chase: call() needs an argument- the scope in wich your callback function gets executed. In your example there is only a global scope so that wont work. Placing the script in a class will allow that if your callbacks are defined in the same class. Otherwise (callbaks are not in the same class) use bind() outside and call callback() directly